# List of upcoming Six months including this month

Tags: java, scala, datetime

i can get the current month in this format
by

```
val dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMM")
dateFormat.format(new Date())//201408
```

but how get

```
List(201408,201409,201410,201411,201412,201501)
```

Comment: You almost certainly *don't* want to use `YYYY`. You probably want `yyyy`. Which version of Java are you using? On Java 8 I'd use `java.time`; before that I'd use Joda Time. It can all be done with `Calendar`, but using either of the others would be nicer.

Comment: Note that your title talks about 7 months, but you've only shown 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Java syntax, but I'm sure you can change it to Scala easily enough.)

In decreasing order of preference...

With Java 8:

```
// TODO: Which time zone are you interested in?
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM");
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    dates.add(formatter.format(yearMonth.plusMonths(i)));
}
```

With Joda Time:

```
// TODO: Which time zone are you interested in?
YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMM");
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    dates.add(formatter.print(yearMonth.plusMonths(i)));
}
```

With `Calendar`:

```
// TODO: Which time zone are you interested in?
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    dates.add(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
```

Comment: I think it is more strict forward to write (use joda time as example): `for (int i = 0; i< 6; i++) { dates.add(formatter.format(yearMonth.plusMonths(i));}`

Comment: @AdrianShum: What do you mean by "strict forward"? Either way will work. I agree that's slightly neater - and I'll fix it - but both should be fine.

Comment: yes either way work.  I just find the way I suggest have a bit more readable with proper naming :)  something like `result.add(inputMonth.plusMonths(i));` is a bit more fluent to read.  (I didn't mean the original way is hard though  :)  )

Answer (score 1):

In **scala**,With Joda Time:

```
val yearMonth = new YearMonth();
val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMM");
val dates = (0 to 5).map {
    i=>formatter.print(yearMonth.plusMonths(i)).toInt 
}.toList
```

Comment: val date = (0 to 5).map (formatter.print(yearMonth.plusMonths(_)).toInt).toList // immutable list